# Example of a covering map that lift some loop to loop but not all.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I want to find a covering map $p: X\rightarrow Y$ and two loops $f,g$ such that $f$ is lifted to a loop in $X$ but $g$ is not lifted to a loop in $X.$ So it seems like two loops $f$ and $g$ must have some different trait to make a different consequence. I was thinking about maybe $f$ can be a loop that can be deformed to a point but $g$ cannot? But I am not sure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the first example of a covering space you know?

Comment: Take everyone's favorite covering map $\mathbb{R} \to S^1$, take $f$ to be a constant loop, and take $g$ to be any loop with nonzero winding number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're entirely right.  You could consider contractible and non-contractible loops lifting under a universal covering.  The "different trait" you reference is the following result:

${\bf Fact:}$ For a based covering $p \colon (\hat{X},\hat{b}) \to (X,b)$, a loop $l$ in $X$ lifts to a loop if and only if $[l] \in p^\ast\pi_1(\hat{X},\hat{b}) \leqslant \pi_1(X,b)$.